# Delete 2 level subfolders but leave 1 level subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, delete-file, subdirectory

my problem is that we have a network share with different subfolders with ACL permissions etc.

I need to keep the 1st level but also need to delete everything in these folders.

`share:\Test1\Test11\...
share:\Test1\Test12\...
share:\Test2\Test21\...
share:\Test2\Test22\...
share:\Test3\Test31\...
share:\Test3\Test32\...
share:\Test...`

The result hast to be:

`share:\Test1\
share:\Test2\
share:\Test3\
share:\Test...`

I found solutions with one root folder but I have multiple with different names, not all is testxxx.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Iterate the 1st level folders
- step in and out the folders with PushD/PopD
- issue an `RD /S /Q . 2>NUL` this will erase all files and folders and try to erase the current folder what will fail thus requirung error output redirection to NUL

---

```
@Echo off
Pushd "share:\"
For /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B/AD') Do (
  Pushd "%%~A"
  RD /S /Q . 2>NUL
  PopD
)
PopD
```